# Nuxt-mail works in local but not in online hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, smtp, nuxt.js

I configured Nuxt-mail to use an external mail server (from the hosting provider) like this:

[image: Nust-mail configuration]

I send the email like the following (test both with Axios and not):

[image: email send]

Everything works fine when I try it from my computer (localhost) as you can see here:

[image: localhost works]

But it fails when I try from the online website:

[image: online website fails]

The Nuxt app is up as static website, I don't know if it makes a difference.
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, please do not post code images but rather actual text.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing a [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+nuxt+mail).

You'll notice what you're trying to achieve (static website) is not feasible. You will indeed need a running node.js server.
PS: websites like Netlify and Vercel do not allow for such thing.

It works locally because you have a webpack dev server running when using your project locally.